# Find exactly string "pattern" with awk when two string have similar words

Tags: awk

I have one file with many lines, I want to get values from columns where this exactly pattern exist: "Enhanced CAR_Red per time", but in the file, there are another string that has similar words: "Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time". I want to look for the fist string only. I tried to put "^" and "$" but they only works at the begining of the line.

Is there some sugestion?

Thanks

This is one exemplo of the lines that contain the original file:

```
Cn Operator Index  Operator Name  License Identifier  Description                                  
0                  DODGE          ID20                Enhanced CAR_Red per time                          
0                  DODGE          ID27                Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time
```

I'm looking for "Enhanced CAR_Red per" to get "License Identifier", but I recibe two registers.

Comment: it would help you to get good answer sooner if you could provide an input example and desired output.

Comment: your file looks like `<tab>` separated??

Comment: Yes, the file are separated by tab (spaces)

Comment: `<tab>` or `spaces`? they are different!

Comment: At the top, they are name of columns, so, I guess, they are tab

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'\t' '$NF~/^Enhanced CAR_Red per/{ print $(NF-1) }' file
```

Comment: I just saw this question and was about to post the same. You beat me my precious ... Gollum Gollum!

Comment: I have a feeling we're just beginning to peel the onion on this one so I think you'll have plenty of opportunity!

Comment: I guess he wanted `$NF=="Enhanced CAR_Red per time"..`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AWK before, but in general when using regular expressions here are some good tricks to solve your problem.

You could add some extra specification to what IS acceptable before "Enhanced CAR_Red per time". If the line should begin with that string, the use "^", but if you know want to allow additional spaces or commas (whatever would denote only this specific term you are searching for) then add them as well.

For example, if you're looking through a list delimited with commas, then make make the term "[, ]*Enhanced CAR_Red per time"

If the term "Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time" is the only occurrence of error you could also specify something along the lines of "Enhanced CAR_Red per time" && !"Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time" to specify that you don't want Wash in there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to suppress the lines with "Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time" before starting `awk`:

```
grep -v "Wash Enhanced CAR_Red per time" yourfile | awk '/Enhanced CAR_Red per time/{print}'
```